# best way to check if something is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering, what's the best way to check if something is null or undefined in JSON arrays or objects in general? For years i've been using

```
if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
   // Value isn't null or undefined
}
```

Comment: You can use `if(!value)` but it will be true for `''` and `0` as well.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I want the most reliable way.

Comment: `value != null` does the same thing as your if-statement, but it's not necessarily better than what you have.

Comment: you can use the loose equality operator against null if(value == null) to check for both null and undefined

Comment: `if (![undefined, null].includes(value))`

Comment: There is no such thing as JSON *array*. In a JSON stringified object, `undefined`  will be converted to `null`

Comment: depending on the logic of the `if` block, you might want to take a look and consider using the nullish coalescing operator `??` or the nullish assignment `??=`

Comment: Your way to do is the most reliable way for me....

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-4f2faa?file=index.js) helps

Comment: @ikhvjs - Reliability isn't a personal preference. The OP's way is reliable, and so is `value != null`. The only issue with the second way is whether future programmers will know the rules well enough to know that's the same thing.

Comment: @tarkh `typeof null` isn't `'null'` it's `'object'`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes, I already fixed this in my answer, and forgot about comment above, thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the loose equality operator `==`.
It will treat `null` and `undefined` as if they were the same.

```js
if (value != null) {
  /* do something with the value if it isn't null AND undefined */
}

if (value == null) {
  /* do something with the value if it is null OR undefined */
}

// Which is the same as this one with the strict equality operator

if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
  /* do something with the value if it isn't null AND undefined */
}

if (value === null || value === undefined) {
  /* do something with the value if it is null OR undefined */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

IMHO using `typeof` for `undefined` is the safest way, because it does not requires variable to be declared at all. Then you can add `value !== null`, so if `value` declared, then check that it is not `Null`. Of course it depends on your project details, code style etc., and there is no such thing as "best"... But if your environment expects situation, where variables could be not declared or you have some dynamic function generation, keep in mind, that `typeof  value !== "undefined"` will handle undeclared variables.

```js
if (typeof value !== "undefined" && value !== null) {
  console.log("exist and not Null");
} else {
  console.log("not exist or Null");
}
```

Below is the example, which will throw error if not using `typeof`:

```js
if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
  console.log("exist and not Null");
} else {
  console.log("not exist or Null");
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, ah, sorry) I mean exactly what you wrote, but lost focus. Fixed. About answers - I agree, stackoverflow needs some feature with merging questions. Anyway thanx for pointing this out.

Comment: I would expect to get an error if I forgot to declare a variable

Comment: so... which one is the best?

Comment: @sdadsasdsa, there is no such thing as "best"... But if your environment expects situation, where variables could be not declared or you have some dynamic function generation, keep in mind, that `typeof  value !== "undefined"` will handle undeclared variables.